# Unable to get the desired output

Tags: administration

I have 3 subject fields Subject1, Subject2, Subject3.

I am trying to run this code -

```
IF( AND( Subject1__c >=  40, Subject2__c  >= 40,Subject3__c >= 40 ),
   if(  AND(Subject1__c  > 40 , Subject1__c <50,
            Subject2__c  > 40, Subject2__c  <50, 
            Subject3__c > 40, Subject3__c <50),'third class',

    if(  AND(Subject1__c  > 50 ,Subject1__c  <60,
             Subject2__c  > 50 ,Subject2__c  <60,
             Subject3__c > 50 ,Subject3__c <60),'second class',

    if( AND(Subject1__c  > 60 , Subject1__c  <70,
            Subject2__c  > 60 ,Subject2__c  <70, 
            Subject3__c > 60 , Subject3__c <70), 'distinction',
'Fail'))),'Not a Valid')
```

But, all I get is either Fail or Invalid, It is not reading the 'first class' , 'second class' or 'distinction'. I kept changing the values in the subject fields but all it does is give me an output of either Fail or Not a valid.

Can you guys plz help. Newbie to SalesForce.

Answer (score 1):

Is this ur logic ? if the score is

- greater than 100 or less than 0 show Not Valid
- greater than 80 in all 3 subjects then its a distinction
- greater than 60 in all 3 subjects then its a second class
- greater than 40 in all 3 subjects then its a third class

if so give this a try..

```
IF( OR(Subject1__c > 100, Subject2__c  > 100,Subject3__c > 100,Subject1__c < 0, Subject2__c  < 0,Subject3__c < 0), 'Not Valid' ,
    IF( AND( Subject1__c > 80, Subject2__c  > 80,Subject3__c > 80 ), 'distinction',
       IF( AND( Subject1__c > 60, Subject2__c  > 60,Subject3__c > 60 ), 'second class',
           IF( AND( Subject1__c > 40, Subject2__c  > 40,Subject3__c > 40 ), 'third class','Fail')
       )
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi @Vamsi Krishna, this is what I want to achieve - greater than 40 and less than 60 - Third class , greater than 60 and less than 80 - Second class , greater than 80 and less than or equal to 100 - Distinction. Can you give me a code for this. ?

Comment: hi @Socio chk my updated answer.. u can change the values as u need.. also make sure to create validation rules to restrict values between 0 & 100 for these fields

Comment: Thanks Vamsi, for the quick response. How about this scenario - If I dont want to enter validation rules and if users enter anything other than 0 to 100 , it should say not valid ? How can we achieve this ?

Comment: you can add in those 2 conditions as nested IF inside the same formula. I will update the same answer above